# ResizeMode.CanResize with AllowsTransparency=true does not work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to create a modern UI style application with WPF (for Win7 and 8). No Titlebar and no thick Window-Border, just like Office 2013 or Photoshop CS4 (or higher).
I have the following settings:

```
<Window
AllowTransparency="true"
ResizeMode="CanResize"
WindowStyle="None">
...
</Window>
```

But I´m not able to resize the Window, because the Border with the resize-functionality is missing. Using CanResizeWithGrip works (i have a grip in the right bottom edge), but is not useful enough: it should be possible to resize the Window anywhere on the Window-Border. Setting BorderThickness of the Window to 1 or higher does not help.

How can I reproduce the missing resizing feature?

Comment: The nchittest windows message decides if mouse is in an area to resize, ve had to override this myself before.to recreate resizing